# Can't simplify a long expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, assumptions

I have a long expression with 7 parameters.
I would like to simplify it so I can use it in another context (not Mathematica).

But I tried everything: Simplify, FullSimplify, Expand then Simplify, Rationalize, I also added assumptions but either it doesn't simplify or it just never shows a result.
All the parameters are real and positive and the result is supposed to be real and positive as well.

Is it possible to simplify this expression more than that? If yes, How?

Here you can have a look at the expression :

[image]

```
-0.5 \[Sqrt](-((2.38095 m)/(25. Na - 6. Ni)) + (
     0.793651 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni))/(
     625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
      36. Ni^2) - (419974. (625. m^2 Na^2 - 300. m^2 Na Ni + 
          36. m^2 Ni^2))/((25. Na - 
          6. Ni)^2 (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni)^3 + 
          2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
             300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
          7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
             36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 2500. Ch m Nh - 
             2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
             252. m Ni x0)^2 + \[Sqrt](-4. (2.75625*10^13 m^2 Na^2 - 
                1.323*10^13 m^2 Na Ni + 
                1.5876*10^12 m^2 Ni^2)^3 + (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na \
- 6. m Ni)^3 + 
               2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
                  300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
               7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
                  36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 
                  2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
                  252. m Ni x0)^2)^2))^(1/3)) - (
     1/((25. Na - 6. Ni)^2))
     5.99925*10^-6 (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni)^3 + 
        2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
           300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
        7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 
           1.05*10^7 m Na - 2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 
           1050. m Na x0 - 
           252. m Ni x0)^2 + \[Sqrt](-4. (2.75625*10^13 m^2 Na^2 - 
              1.323*10^13 m^2 Na Ni + 
              1.5876*10^12 m^2 Ni^2)^3 + (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na - 
                6. m Ni)^3 + 
             2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
                300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
             7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
                36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 
                2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
                252. m Ni x0)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + 
 0.5 \[Sqrt](-((2.38095 m)/(25. Na - 6. Ni)) - (
     0.793651 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni))/(
     625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
      36. Ni^2) + (419974. (625. m^2 Na^2 - 300. m^2 Na Ni + 
          36. m^2 Ni^2))/((25. Na - 
          6. Ni)^2 (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni)^3 + 
          2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
             300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 

          7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
             36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 2500. Ch m Nh - 
             2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
             252. m Ni x0)^2 + \[Sqrt](-4. (2.75625*10^13 m^2 Na^2 - 
                1.323*10^13 m^2 Na Ni + 
                1.5876*10^12 m^2 Ni^2)^3 + (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na \
- 6. m Ni)^3 + 
               2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
                  300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
               7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
                  36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 
                  2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
                  252. m Ni x0)^2)^2))^(1/3)) + (
     1/((25. Na - 6. Ni)^2))
     5.99925*10^-6 (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni)^3 + 
        2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
           300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
        7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 
           1.05*10^7 m Na - 2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 
           1050. m Na x0 - 
           252. m Ni x0)^2 + \[Sqrt](-4. (2.75625*10^13 m^2 Na^2 - 
              1.323*10^13 m^2 Na Ni + 
              1.5876*10^12 m^2 Ni^2)^3 + (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na - 
                6. m Ni)^3 + 
             2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
                300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
             7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
                36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 
                2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
                252. m Ni x0)^2)^2))^(
      1/3) + (0.00113379 (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 
          2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
          252. m Ni x0))/((25. Na - 
          6. Ni)^2 \[Sqrt](-((2.38095 m)/(25. Na - 6. Ni)) + (
           0.793651 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni))/(
           625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
            36. Ni^2) - (419974. (625. m^2 Na^2 - 300. m^2 Na Ni + 
                36. m^2 Ni^2))/((25. Na - 
                6. Ni)^2 (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni)^3 + 
                2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
                   300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
                7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
                   36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 
                   2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
                   252. m Ni x0)^2 + \[Sqrt](-4. (2.75625*10^13 m^2 \
Na^2 - 1.323*10^13 m^2 Na Ni + 
                    1.5876*10^12 m^2 Ni^2)^3 + (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m \
Na - 6. m Ni)^3 + 
                    2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 
                    6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
                    7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
                    36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 
                    2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
                    252. m Ni x0)^2)^2))^(1/3)) - (
           1/((25. Na - 6. Ni)^2))
           5.99925*10^-6 (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni)^3 + 
              2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 
                 300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
              7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
                 36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 
                 2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
                 252. m Ni x0)^2 + \[Sqrt](-4. (2.75625*10^13 m^2 \
Na^2 - 1.323*10^13 m^2 Na Ni + 
                    1.5876*10^12 m^2 Ni^2)^3 + (-2.31525*10^15 (25. m \
Na - 6. m Ni)^3 + 
                   2.08373*10^16 m^2 (25. m Na - 
                    6. m Ni) (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 36. Ni^2) - 
                   7.44188*10^8 (625. Na^2 - 300. Na Ni + 
                    36. Ni^2) (25. g m^2 - 1.05*10^7 m Na - 
                    2500. Ch m Nh - 2.16*10^6 m Ni + 1050. m Na x0 - 
                    252. m Ni x0)^2)^2))^(1/3))))
```

Here is the code that is above the expression (How I get this result). In this case A is the expression:

```
Ci = (10.08*x + 86400)/100;
Ca = (-42*x + 420000)/100;
Fh = Nh*100*Ch;
Fa = Na*100*Ca;
Fi = Ni*100*Ci;
F = Fh + Fa + Fi;

x[t_] = FullSimplify[Solve[(F/m - g)*t^2/2 + x0 == x, x][[1, 1, 2]]]

A = Solve[{x'[t] == 100}, t][[4, 1, 2]]
```

P.S. I tried to replace the parameters with actual values and the result was correct so I guess the expression is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the actual code, not the an image of the code.

Comment: I can't, when I try to add the code, it becomes half in code format and half in script format.

Comment: Try pasting the code, then select it and hit the `{}` button, this should shift everything by four spaces, and make sure everything is formatted code.

Comment: you have effectively a fourth order polynomial in t. I'm afraid there isn't much hope for simplification.

Comment: You could replace `(F/m - g)` with `(a + b x)`

Comment: Since you know actual values, what the constraints on the parameters? Are any real, nonnegative, or positive? Adding these constraints/assumptions may help.

Comment: I know parameters for only one case but they can change (all of them) in other cases so I need the expression. All parameters are reals and positive and I already tried to add these assumptions without any better result. And when I add the assumption: `A>0` it never shows the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments you can write $x[t]$ as

```
x[t_] = FullSimplify[Solve[(a x + b)*t^2/2 + x0 == x, x][[1, 1, 2]]];
```

With

```
    a=(-42 Na + (252 Ni)/25)/m
```

and

```
    b=-g + (420000 Na + 100 Ch Nh + 86400 Ni)/m
```

This gives you

```
x[t_]:=(b t^2 + 2 x0)/(2 - a t^2);
```

With that you get a much shorter expression for A.
As

```
Simplify[A] /. {(-27 a^2 b^2 - 27 a^4 x0^2 - 
 2 a^3 (320000 + 27 b x0) + 
 3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
  a^4 (b + a x0)^2 (1280000 a + 27 b^2 + 54 a b x0 + 
     27 a^2 x0^2)]) -> w}
```

> Sqrt[400/a - (16000 10^(1/3))/w^(1/3) - (10^(2/3) w^(1/3))/a^2]/(
>    10 Sqrt[6]) + 
>    1/2 Sqrt[16/(3 a) + (320 10^(1/3))/(3 w^(1/3)) + w^(1/3)/(
>      15 10^(1/3) a^2) - (2 Sqrt[6] (b + a x0))/(
>      5 a^2 Sqrt[
>       400/a - (16000 10^(1/3))/w^(1/3) - (10^(2/3) w^(1/3))/a^2])]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This makes it much easier for me ! I haven't thought about it ! And thanks to Simon Woods for bringing the idea !